# Rails: Globalize3 and batch_translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, translation, globalize3

I'm using rails 3.2.8, globalize3 and batch_translations to translate specific content for an little cms and shop system.
I integrated it without problems for one translation on one model. So everthings works fine. I started adding this functionality for my other models and..shhhhh weird things happen.

Status now: I can create new content with translations. Everything ok. But if I try to edit/update the values in the translations tables nothing happen! Maybe there is a wrong parameter path in batch_translations or something...

Here an example for categories!

migration_file

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    Category.create_translation_table! :category_name => :string, :description => :string
  end

  def self.down
    Category.drop_translation_table!
    drop_table :categories
  end
end
```

model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_name, :description

  attr_accessible :translations_attributes
  translates :category_name, :description
  has_many :translations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations

  class Translation
    attr_accessible :locale, :category_name, :description
  end
end
```

this weird class Translation I wrote because I got mass-assignemnt errors for locale, etc...

form:

```
<div>
  <%= form_for @category, html: { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= build_translation_text_field f, :category_name, :description  %>
    <%= f.submit (t ".save"), class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

helper for my translation form:

```
def build_translation_text_field(f, *atts)
  tag = content_tag(:h1, "Test")
  I18n.available_locales.each do |l|
    f.globalize_fields_for l do |g|
      atts.each do |a|
        tag += content_tag(:div, content_tag(:h4, t(a)+":"))
        tag += (g.text_field a, class: l)
      end
    end
  end
  tag
end
```

categories_controller update method:

```
def create
  @category = Category.new(params[:category])
  if @category.save
    @categories = Category.all
    flash[:success] = t(:category_created)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render 'index'}
      format.js
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = @category.errors.full_messages.each {|msg| p msg}
    @categories = Category.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render 'new'}
      format.js
    end
  end
end

def update
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
    @categories = Category.all
    flash[:success] = t(:category_updated)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render 'index'}
      format.js
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = @category.errors.full_messages.each {|msg| p msg}
    @categories = Category.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render 'edit'}
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

anyone an idea or have an working example with two models whit one or more translated attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault:

Update for the model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_name, :description

  attr_accessible :translations_attributes
  translates :category_name, :description
  # has_many :translations <-- delete this
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations

  class Translation
    attr_accessible :locale, :category_name, :description
  end
end
```